# Problem with setting worflows rules for pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, workflow, pipeline

I have a problem with setting rules for the pipeline. I need to set when the pipeline is running and when is not running for $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE. But somewhere is the problem.

I need rules:

if the commit message is "Generated doc for KMP" then stop the pipeline

if the commit message is not "Generated doc for KMP" then run the pipeline

```
variables:
  CI_DOKKA_KMP: "Generated doc for KMP"
  
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE == "$CI_DOKKA_KMP"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CI_DOKKA_KMP: "[ci skip]Generated doc for KMP"

workflow:
 rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[ci skip\]/
     when: never
   - when: always
```

It's solved :)